# Root diameter and the base diameter of gear and pinion

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics

In my design of a spurgear
the root diameter in pinion is less than the base diameter
but in the gear
the base diameter is less than the root diameter.

Why?

Comment: I think your question is related to this [question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13852/involute-gear-curve-when-root-diameter-falls-below-base-diameter)

Comment: You are probably undercutting the pinion, likely if it has a low number of teeth. Answer @NMech linked goes into deeper detail.